# Plotly responsive dropdown menu

Tags: python, plotly

Is there a way to make the dropdown menus in Plotly responsive (whenever the screen size is decreased, the dropdown menus should reflect the change and shrink).

When I decrease the window size the boxes are displayed one on another, and some labels are shown and some are not shown:
[image: Dropdown menus are not responsive]

here is a json file:

```
{
"Names": {
    "0": "Alice",
    "1": "Robert",
    "2": "Garry",
    "3": "Nate",
    "4": "Karen",
    "5": "Nick"
},
"Address": {
    "0": "21 Main St",
    "1": "19 Third St",
    "2": "4 Church St",
    "3": "5 High St",
    "4": "9 Elm St",
    "5": "06 Washingtom St"
},
"AreaCode": {
    "0": "777",
    "1": "421",
    "2": "768",
    "3": "345",
    "4": "888",
    "5": "123"
}}
```

here is a python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


df_data = pd.read_json("test.json")


button_x_list = []
button_y_list = []
button_graphs_list = []

colnames = df_data.keys()

null_x = dict(
    method="update",
    label="",
    visible=True,
    args=[
        {"x": ["" for _ in range(len(df_data))]},
        {"xaxis": {"title": ""}},
    ],
)

null_y = dict(
    method="update",
    label="",
    visible=True,
    args=[
        {"y": ["" for _ in range(len(df_data))]},
        {"yaxis": {"title": ""}},
    ],
)

button_x_list.append(null_x)
button_y_list.append(null_y)

for col in colnames:
    button_x_list.append(
        dict(
            method="update",
            label=col,
            visible=True,
            args=[
                {"x": [df_data[col]]},
                {"xaxis": {"title": col}},
            ],
        )
    )

    button_y_list.append(
        dict(
            method="update",
            label=col,
            visible=True,
            args=[
                {"y": [df_data[col]]},
                {"yaxis": {"title": col}},
            ],
        )
    )


button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(args=["type", "scatter"], label="Bubble", method="restyle")
)
button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(args=["type", "bar"], label="Bar", method="restyle")
)
button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(args=["type", "pie"], label="Pie", method="restyle")
)
button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(args=["type", "histogram"], label="Histogram", method="restyle")
)
button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(args=["type", "box"], label="Box", method="restyle")
)



button_x_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_x_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.03,
    y=1.08,
)

button_y_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_y_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.23,
    y=1.08,
)

button_graphs_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_graphs_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.46,
    y=1.08,
)

annotation_x = dict(
    text="X:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)
annotation_y = dict(
    text="Y:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0.2,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)
annotation_graphs = dict(
   text="Graph:",
   showarrow=False,
   x=0.4,
   y=1.05,
   xanchor="left",
   xref="paper",
   yref="paper",
   align="left",
   yanchor="top",
)

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(x=pd.Series(dtype=object), y=pd.Series(dtype=object), mode="markers")
)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[button_x_dict, button_y_dict, button_graphs_dict],
    annotations=[annotation_x, annotation_y, annotation_graphs],
    title="Plotly Demo",
    xaxis={"title": ""},
    yaxis={"title": ""}
 )

 fig.show()
```

Comment: The elements overlap each other passed some point, so I guess you can try to set some styles to each one in order to override this behavior (ie. min width, margin/padding, etc.). But with such small screen size, how do you expect them to be displayed ? I would wrap the dropdowns inside a container, and using an external stylesheet with media queries, apply some flex properties, for example to stack the dropdown vertically when the screen width is to small.

Comment: I don't have a specific way it has to be displayed, whichever is easier I guess, I just want to make sure they are displayed nicely even when the screen size is changed. They could even be displayed on the left side of the screen initially one above the other.